Hyper-V not found in Windows Features
I am trying to enable hardware acceleration for an android emulator for   my .NET MAUI project on Visual Studio with Hyper-V (Windows 10). The emulator keeps crashing because I don't have Hyper-V.
ERROR   | x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator hypervisor driver is not installed on this machine

I was following this tutorial from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration?view=net-maui-8.0
I checked my systeminfo in an admin cmd and this was the section for Hyper-V:
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

I then open the turn Windows features on or off app and didn't find the folder for Hyper-V.
Here is an image of the list of features:
List of features on my PC
Another thing I tried to do was to input commands to do it manually like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/74708229/23941560
but they both ended in an error. (the commands used are in this other question and you can find them on multiple websites for this problem) CMD:
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.3636

Image Version: 10.0.19045.4780


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

POWERSHELL:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand```



I am trying to enable hardware acceleration for an android emulator for my .NET MAUI project on Visual Studio with Hyper-V (Windows 10). The emulator keeps crashing because I don't have Hyper-V.

Hyper-V isn't actually required for .NET MAUI projects.  You only need AEHD acceleration to be enabled. One of the requirements for AEHD acceleration is that Hyper-V is disabled.
In order to enable AEHD acceleration you need to do the following:


In Visual Studio, select the Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager... menu item.
In the Android SDKs and Tools window, select the Tools tab.
In the Tools tab, expand Extras, tick the checkbox for the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver (installer) item, and then select the Apply
Changes button: 
Make sure that the virtual device you created in the Android Device Manager is an x86-64 or x86-based system image. If you use
an Arm-based system image, the virtual device won't be accelerated and
will run slowly.


Source: Enable AEHD acceleration in Windows

I then open the turn Windows features on or off app and didn't find the folder for Hyper-V.

If you need Hyper-V you will need to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional

Hyper-V requires the Pro license of Windows 10.
If you are running Windows 10 Home edition, Hyper-V will not show as an available feature.
While it may be possible to "hack" a solution to enable Hyper-V in Windows 10 Home, the answer to your question is: You need to be running Windows 10 Professional in order to see the Hyper-V feature and enable it.
